# Tricky Notations in C

Tags: c++, c

What does those notations refer to ? What am i declaring ? I have a hard problem identifying what is being declared

```
1 - double (*b)[n];  
2 - double (*c[n])();  
3 - double (*d())[n];
```

And i can't even think in understanding this one

```
double (*foo(double (*) (double, double[]),double)) (double, ...);
```

Overall, if there is any logic or step-by-step i can use for almost all ( or preferably al )
cases, would be really great to know.

Comment: Take a look at the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: For many cases there is the nifty gadget at [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Comment: Thanks, i did search a lot but didn't know the keywords for finding material about such topic

Comment: Hey, can't thank enough for the spiral rule site, i just figured out all examples. cdecl gadget was rly nice to save some time too,i'm saving it. Realy impressive how the community here is quick and proficient

Comment: but in all honesty... why?  it's so easy to confuse, and not everyone is a c++ veteran. if you work in a team, chances are that using something like this is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: True, type aliases and some sort of `identity` template would make these much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double (*b)[n];
```

This is a pointer named `b` that points to an array of `double`s that has length `n`.

```
double (*c[n])();
```

This is an array named `c` of `n` pointers to functions that take in unspecified arguments (in C) or no arguments (in C++) and return `double`s.

```
double (*d())[n];
```

This is a function named `d` that returns a pointer to an array of `n` `double`s.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm just curious where are you going to use the last one?

Comment: @chris- Oh whoops - I misread my own answer and thought it returned an array of doubles.  Never mind...

Comment: @templatetypedef, Ah, that would be why.